# How to override getItem()?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

These are part of the code:

```
public class Fruit {
    private String name;
    private int imageId;
    public Fruit(String name, int imageId) {

        this.name = name;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getName() {
       return name;
 }
    public int getImageId() {
       return imageId;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FruitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fruit> {

       private int resourceId;

       public FruitAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
           List<Fruit> objects) {
               super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
               resourceId = textViewResourceId;
       }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
          Fruit fruit = getItem(position); // get the current Fruit instance.
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, null);
          ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_image);
          TextView fruitName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
          fruitImage.setImageResource(fruit.getImageId());
          fruitName.setText(fruit.getName());
          return view;
  }
}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initFruits();

    FruitAdapter adapter = new FruitAdapter(MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.fruit_item, fruitList);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


  }

  private void initFruits() {
    Fruit apple = new Fruit("Apple", R.drawable.apple);
    fruitList.add(apple);
    Fruit banana = new Fruit("Banana", R.drawable.banana);
    fruitList.add(banana);
    Fruit orange = new Fruit("Orange", R.drawable.orange);
    fruitList.add(orange);
    Fruit watermelon = new Fruit("Watermelon", R.drawable.watermelon);
    fruitList.add(watermelon);
    Fruit pear = new Fruit("Pear", R.drawable.pear);
    fruitList.add(pear);
    Fruit grape = new Fruit("Grape", R.drawable.grape);
    fruitList.add(grape);
    Fruit pineapple = new Fruit("Pineapple", R.drawable.pineapple);
    fruitList.add(pineapple);
    Fruit strawberry = new Fruit("Strawberry", R.drawable.strawberry);
    fruitList.add(strawberry);
    Fruit cherry = new Fruit("Cherry", R.drawable.cherry);
    fruitList.add(cherry);
    Fruit mango = new Fruit("Mango", R.drawable.mango);
    fruitList.add(mango);
  }
}
```

The `getItem()` method returns a `String`, but I want a `Fruit` instance. How to override it? I don't know how to use the position parameter.

All above are the sourse codes..I don't put the XML.The fruit_item.xml inclde a TextView and an ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the list to a class variable and access it

```
public class FruitAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fruit> {

       private int resourceId;
       private List<Fruit> mObjects;     
       public FruitAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
           List<Fruit> objects) {
               super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
               resourceId = textViewResourceId;
                mObjects =objects;
       }
       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
          Fruit fruit = mObjexts.get(position); // get the current Fruit instance.
          View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resourceId, null);
          ImageView fruitImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_image);
          TextView fruitName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fruit_name);
          fruitImage.setImageResource(fruit.getImageId());
          fruitName.setText(fruit.getName());
          return view;
  }
}
```

you can also override getItem()

```
@Override
       public Fruit getItem(int position) {
             mObjects.get[position];
       }
```

Comment: Thanks..But can you override getItem() for me ?I want to know how to use  it.

Comment: I got a  List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>().in MainActivity.

Comment: I type the code according to a book,but it's seems miss the override of getItem()